# Grabbing a view later in the hierarchy of a navigation controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I've got a navigation controller with a couple of view controllers in the stack. In the 2nd view, I present a new view that is not embedded in the navigation controller with `presentViewController(...)`. Once the user is finished with this individual view, I would like to go back to the 2nd view in which programmatically presented the individual view. However, when I `presentViewController(...)` to the 2nd view, it is no longer embedded in the navigation controller.

How am I able to get back to the 2nd view without having to go back to the root view controller? Thanks!

Comment: Does 2nd view controller keep residing in the navigation stack when your view is presented or is it popped out by navigation controller for some reason after it presents your view controller?

Comment: I assume it resides in the navigation controller, since I do not pop it. How would I be able to fetch it again? Or am I able to remove the individual view controller from the screen some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are currently at the view controller presented by 2nd view controller:

```
UIViewController *secondViewController = self.presentingViewController;

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [secondViewController.navigationController popToViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}];
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks so much.